# What is "Gelatine (Plant)"? Is it halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I was shopping for snacks yesterday, and I saw a new product (not sure where from; I'm in Canada but as there was Chinese writing on the package I assume it was foreign).  Among the ingredients was one listed as "Gelatine (Plant)".

I know that vegetarian products are (in general) *halal*, so the "(Plant)" strongly suggests *halality*.  However, while there are a number of gelling agents which come from plants, gelatine itself is derived from collagen: To the best of my knowledge this is animal protein and *never comes from plants*.

So what is this stuff?  Is it *halal*?

Comment: I can only assume they mean a `plant substitute for gelatin`, and write `plant gelatin` for short.

Comment: I often see that 'Plant Gelatin' is often referred to as a gelling agent in the ingredients.

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is right. Gelatin is derived from animals. However, there are some gelling agents such as [pectin that come from plants](http://blogs.library.duke.edu/answerperson/2007/03/12/gelatin/). These are carbohydrate based and are not chemically related to animal gelatin. I think these are called vegetable gelatin and might be what you saw on the label.  When it comes to whether it’s Halal, I suggest you make your own judgment(You are more qualified than I). But again, If it’s veggie based, I don't see any problem with it.